# Error in the delete function of the alarm app in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My app crashes whenever I press the Delete button from the simulator in iPhone. I have copied some code from my project here. How can I solve the delete bug?

**EnableAlarm.h file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EnableAlarm : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

    IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
    IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
    IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;
    NSMutableArray *arraydata;
}
-(IBAction) btnReturn:(id) sender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *tableview;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *eventText;

- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender;
- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender;

@end
```

**EnableAlarm.m**

```
#import "EnableAlarm.h"

@implementation EnableAlarm

-(IBAction) btnReturn:(id) sender
{
    [self.view removeFromSuperview];

}
@synthesize datePicker,tableview, eventText;

- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

- (IBAction) scheduleAlarm:(id) sender {
    [eventText resignFirstResponder];

    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar autoupdatingCurrentCalendar];

    // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Break the date up into components
    NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [calendar components:( NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];
    NSDateComponents *timeComponents = [calendar components:( NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit | NSSecondCalendarUnit )
                                                   fromDate:pickerDate];

    // Set up the fire time
    NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [dateComps setDay:[dateComponents day]];
    [dateComps setMonth:[dateComponents month]];
    [dateComps setYear:[dateComponents year]];
    [dateComps setHour:[timeComponents hour]];
    // Notification will fire in one minute
    [dateComps setMinute:[timeComponents minute]];
    [dateComps setSecond:[timeComponents second]];
    NSDate *itemDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:dateComps];
    [dateComps release];

    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotif == nil)
        return;
    localNotif.fireDate = itemDate;
    localNotif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];

    // Notification details
    localNotif.alertBody = [eventText text];
    // Set the action button
    localNotif.alertAction = @"View";

    localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // Specify custom data for the notification
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
    localNotif.userInfo = infoDict;

    // Schedule the notification
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotif];
    [localNotif release];

    [self.tableview reloadData];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    int count = [arraydata count];
    if(self.editing) count++;


    return [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count];
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    int count = 0;
    if(self.editing && indexPath.row != 0)
        count = 1;
    // Configure the cell...

    NSArray *arraydata = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications];
    UILocalNotification *notif = [arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

   [cell.textLabel setText:notif.alertBody];
    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[notif.fireDate description]];

    return cell;
}


- (IBAction) EditTable:(id)sender{
    if(self.editing)
    {
        [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [tableview setEditing:NO animated:NO];
        [tableview reloadData];
        //[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
        //[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
    }
    else
    {
        [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [tableview setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        [tableview reloadData];
        //[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
        //[self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
    }
}

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {

//  arraydata = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:nil];;
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // No editing style if not editing or the index path is nil.
    //if (self.editing == NO || !indexPath) return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
    // Determine the editing style based on whether the cell is a placeholder for adding content or already
    // existing content. Existing content can be deleted.
    if (self.editing && indexPath.row == ([arraydata count])) {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    } else {
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
    }


    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}

// Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)TableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
       [arraydata removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

     NSString *item = [[arraydata objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] retain];

        [arraydata removeObject:item];
       [TableView  removeFromSuperview:indexPath.row];
       [item release];

    //if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
    //  [arraydata removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //  NSMutableArray * mArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfURL:theNewURL];
    //  [mArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [tableview deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [tableview reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark Row reordering
// Determine whether a given row is eligible for reordering or not.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

// Process the row move. This means updating the data model to correct the item indices.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath
      toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {
    NSString *item = [[arraydata objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row] retain];
    [arraydata removeObject:item];
    [arraydata insertObject:item atIndex:toIndexPath.row];
    [item release];
}

// The designated initializer.  Override if you create the controller programmatically and want to perform customization that is not appropriate for viewDidLoad.
/*
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization.
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc. that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
   [super viewDidUnload];
    datePicker = nil;
    tableview = nil;
    eventText = nil;

    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some problems I've found:

- In `tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:` the if-statement has no effect, because if- and else-branch return the same value
- Don't call `removeFromSuperview` unless you have added the view (i.e. with `addSubview`) yourself
- You don't need to call `[tableview reloadData]` in `viewWillAppear`
- In `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` the local int-variable `count` has no effect
- In `tableView:commitEditingStyle:` remove the line '`[TableView  removeFromSuperview:indexPath.row];`'. This method does not exist; this is probably the reason why it crashes.
- You remove 2 items from the array `arraydata`. This it probably not what you want.
- You don't need these retain/release-calls in `tableView:commitEditingStyle:`
- Clean-up in `dealloc` is missing
- Recommendation: all methods and variables should start with a lower-case letter